# Bind a textbox value in a label box using c# inside a uframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, uframe

I have entered a value in text box and click the button the value should bind in a label.
The code must be in c# not in query. There is no database also.how please say the code behind in c#. It is button click event. while click the button the page should post back and bind the data how to bind a textbox value in a label box using c#. The value must bind in postback method.

Comment: Provide some code that you have tried so that we can better help you.

Comment: Please show your current code so we can provide a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

It as easy as the following:

```
LabelID.Text = TextBoxID.Text;
```

Where `LabelID` is the ID of your Label control and `TextBoxID` is the ID of your TextBox control.

You should place this code inside the button click's event.

**Update**

Please use for your purpose [ASP.NET Web Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386416(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBoxId" runat="server"/>

<asp:Label ID="labelId" runat="server"/>
```

Then you can access the values of `Text` property of both the above controls, like above:

```
labelId.Text = textBoxId.Text;
```

Comment: Hi, when you say it is an error. What type of error? what's the message's error?

Comment: system.ui.web.htmlcontrols is missing said i added that too and also error showing

Comment: Ah you use an html control. I got it. You should use asp.net web controls instead of using htmlcontrols. Otherwise you cannot access server sice the textt's value (at least easily).

Comment: @user3931943 is it ok now?

Comment: i page reloading but not binding

Comment: You mean that you have entered text inside the text box then clicked the button and nothing happened ( the label's text ) wasn't updated.

Comment: could you please both your markup code and your code behind class code?

Answer (score 1):

easy , take a look at the below code:

```
<asp:TextBox Id="txt1" runat="server" />

<asp:button Id="btn1" runat="server" onClick="Button1_Click"/>
<asp:Label Id="lbl1" runat="server"/>
```

//in the code behind implement the Button1_Click

```
protected void Button1_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{

lbl1.Text= txt1.Text;

}
```

Comment: its .Text (case sensitive on the T)

Comment: I see it looks like your using HTML controls, these are asp.net controls so you have to specify <Asp:TextBox or <Asp:Label and not <input type="text"/>